# Django path to templates for apps

Tags: python, django, templates

Let's assume I have the following project:

```
myproject/
    myproject/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        templates/
            base.html
    app1/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        templates/
            base.html
            index.html
```

I want to have a base template, which all other apps will use, in `myproject/template/base.html`.
Then, I want to have the app templates in `app/templates`.

One option would be writting in myproject/settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/dir/to/myproject/myproject/templates",
    "/dir/to/myproject/app1/templates",
)
```

But, is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django supports this automatically, via the `app_directories` loader that is installed by default. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader).

Comment: One more thing, how do I `{% extends "base.html" %}` from the `app` directory to the `projectname` directory?

Comment: That should just work: as long as the filesystem loader is listed first, it will look in the main template directory first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do the following:

```
#settings.py
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'app1/templates'),
)
```

This will save you from editing each and every absolute path in setting file in case you happen to move your project.